# Change the column label? e.g.: change column "A" to column "Name"

Tags: excel

Can anyone tell me how to change the column label?

For example, I want to change Column "A" to Column "Name" in `Excel`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What version of Excel?

In general, you cannot change the column letters. They are part of the Excel system.

You can use a row in the sheet to enter headers for a table that you are using. The table headers can be descriptive column names.

In Excel 2007 and later, you can convert a range of data into an Excel Table (Insert Ribbon > Table). An Excel Table can use structured table references instead of cell addresses, so the labels in the first row of the table now serve as a name reference for the data in the column.

If you have an Excel Table in your sheet (Excel 2007 and later) and scroll down, the column letters will be replaced with the column headers for the table column.

[image]

If this does not answer your question, please consider editing your question to include the detail you want to learn about.

Comment: Thanks !  
I was searching for this.

Comment: You wrote: "If you have an Excel Table in your sheet and scroll down, the column letters will be replaced with the column headers for the table column." This only works if the first row hasn't been frozen.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl As you can clearly see in my screenshot, there is no frozen first row. Otherwise you would see that row number. You can clearly see that INSTEAD of the column letters A and B, there are the column headings of the table. Not in thefirst row, but in the column headings. For this, your data must be in an Excel table. Not just the grid, but a table inserted with Insert > Table or Ctrl+T.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just wanted to point out to future readers, that if they have frozen the first row and then try your solution, it won't work. Maybe you could start your solution with "Please check if you have any frozen rows. If so, unfreeze them first.".

Answer (score 9):

I would like to present another answer to this as the currently accepted answer doesn't work for me (I use LibreOffice). This solution should work in Excel, LibreOffice and OpenOffice:

First, insert a new row at the beginning of the sheet. Within that row, define the names you need:
[image: new row]

Then, in the menu bar, go to View -> Freeze Cells -> Freeze First Row. It'll look like this now:
[image: new top row]

Now whenever you scroll down in the document, the first row will be "pinned" to the top:
[image: new behaviour]

Comment: Why take the trouble to post a solution for LibreOffice in an Excel question? The two applications are clearly different. Nobody will look for LibreOffice solutions when the question is about Excel. What a waste of time. It's like "What is the word for `love` in German?" and your answer is "In French, it's `amour`" - You missed the point. By the way, Excel can freeze rows and columns, too, even before Libre Office existed, but that was NOT the question. The question is about changing the column headers, not the first row of data. Just saying.

Comment: @teylyn I needed a solution for libreoffice, this question was the first (and one of the only) results. I bet many other LibreOffice users looking for this come/came across this question too. Plus: My solution should work with Excel too.

Comment: I'm using Excel and didn't notice it had a "Freeze first row" option under the View tab, so this actually helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to change A, B, C.... you see high above the columns, you can not. You can hide A, B, C...:
Button Office(top left)
Excel Options(bottom)
Advanced(left)
Right looking: Display options fot this worksheet:
Select the worksheet(eg. Sheet3)
Uncheck: Show column and row headers
Ok