# How to change the name of a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the names of the columns in an Excel sheet.

[image]

I want to rename the column headers as in the image.

Comment: You mean, like, A, B, C, etc.?

Comment: Ya, the current names of Column A is A and Col B is B. I want to rename them as Apple and Banana.

Comment: Range("A:A").Name = "Apple"

Comment: All I know how to do is change them to 1, 2, 3, etc. Now if you want to change header names placed in row 1, you could do `Cells(1,1) = "Apple" Cells(1,2) = "Banana"`, etc.

Comment: @DavidG I don't think that is what the OP wants. I believe OP wants the greyed column letters to change to something more descriptive.

Comment: I have added a picture to better communicate my question.

Comment: The picture doesn't help me. You should continue with your apples and bananas examples since that's what you started with. Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107852/change-the-column-label-e-g-change-column-a-to-column-name If you want the [E][F][G] to become [A][B][C] you can't.

Comment: @DavidG: Sorry, i thought the image would convey a better message. Matt's solution worked. Thanks matt.

Comment: @Raj - you got 2 answers in addition to comments; feel free to accept/upv. a helpful one :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if there is more than one area with these headers, so my solution will work for several. Unfortunately it will work for a maximum of 26 columns, one for each letter of the alphabet. You can expand it if you want.
I've included workbook and worksheet names, these are particular to me, you'll obviously have to change them.
The code looks for areas of data and steps through them, changing the headers on each one. You can adapt the code to just do one area of course. The code starts in the top left of the area, and steps across one cell at a time until it runs out of data, then it moves onto the next area.

```
Sub NewColumnNames()

Dim FruityColumnNames(26) As String
Dim a As Integer
Dim Alphabetical As Integer

FruityColumnNames(1) = "Apple"
FruityColumnNames(2) = "Banana"
FruityColumnNames(3) = "Cherry"
FruityColumnNames(4) = "Damson"
FruityColumnNames(5) = "Elderberry"
FruityColumnNames(6) = "Fig"
FruityColumnNames(7) = "Gooseberry"
FruityColumnNames(8) = "Hawthorn"
FruityColumnNames(9) = "Ita palm"
FruityColumnNames(10) = "Jujube"
FruityColumnNames(11) = "Kiwi"
FruityColumnNames(12) = "Lime"
FruityColumnNames(13) = "Mango"
FruityColumnNames(14) = "Nectarine"
FruityColumnNames(15) = "Orange"
FruityColumnNames(16) = "Passion fruit"
FruityColumnNames(17) = "Quince"
FruityColumnNames(18) = "Raspberry"
FruityColumnNames(19) = "Sloe"
FruityColumnNames(20) = "Tangerine"
FruityColumnNames(21) = "Ugli"
FruityColumnNames(22) = "Vanilla"
FruityColumnNames(23) = "Watermelon"
FruityColumnNames(24) = "Xigua"
FruityColumnNames(25) = "Yumberry"
FruityColumnNames(26) = "Zucchini"

With Workbooks("TestBook.xlsx")
    With .Worksheets("Destination")
        With .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            For a = .Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
                Alphabetical = 1
                With .Areas(a)
                    While (.Cells(1, Alphabetical) <> "" And Alphabetical <= 26)
                        .Cells(1, Alphabetical).Value = FruityColumnNames(Alphabetical)
                        Alphabetical = Alphabetical + 1
                    Wend
                End With
            Next a
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example call** *(with reduced code)*:

```
Sub ChangeHeaderNames()
Dim headers: headers = Split("Apple,Banana,Cherry", ",")     
Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers  ' << change to sheet's Code(Name)
End Sub
```